# Version of Python for Pil and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

What version of python is compatible with both pil and tinter? I have been trying to install them both for ages and have thought maybe that i am trying to install them on incompatible versions. If anyone knows how to do this please explain because i am stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used most 2.7+ versions of Python with Tkinter without problems, however PIL is not generally recommended as it is not updated much anymore. There's a fork called Pillow which I believe most would recommend using instead:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/

It's pretty much a drop-in replacement and your PIL related code shouldn't have to change.